# Play video from (xampp)server as live through an android application

Tags: android

I need to play a video stored on my xampp server, as if it was a live stream through an android application. 
For example: After installing my application on a smartphone, when a user A(say)  makes an access to the xampp server to play the video, the video starts to play on his smartphone device. Now, suppose a user B (say) plays the same video through the server it starts from the same instance as to where User A is now watching the video. Thus, the video being played though stored, becomes live.

I need to demonstrate a concept through this application, and as I have no prior experience in Android Development, so it would be great if anyone can give me any ideas, on how can I approach this, any suggestions/sample code/alternate methods to achieve this please let me know.

Thanks for the time you put in reading my question.